# How to disable OnClick() event when user clicks on winform created by Ironpython?

Tags: python-2.7, winforms, mono, ironpython

I'm writing an Ironpython 2.7.5 code to display Winform and take inputs from the user. Whenever i accidentally clicks on form, it throws error "OnClick() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)". How shall i disable this event?

I've used Notepad++ to write my code and running it in ANSYS tool. Below is the structure of my code:

```
def init(context):
    #Something here
def OpenForm1(analysis_obj):
    form = SimpleTextBoxForm()
    Application.Run(form)
class SimpleTextBoxForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = 'Material Tool V1.0'
        self.Size = Size(Width, Height)
        self.MaximizeBox = False
        self.MinimizeBox = False
        self.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
        #Some other controls
    def OnChanged(self, sender, event):         #Triggered on change
        #Some Code
    def OnClick(self, sender, event):           #Triggered on button clicks
        try:
            #Something here
        except:
            #Something here
```

I want to stop this event from triggering wherever i click on form. But i am unable to.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question correctly. But you're saying you don't need the `OnClick()` event? So why don't you take it out or comment it out? The last 5 lines... I'm very basick at python, so maybe you can't do that, but from winform point of view it should be OK.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 I need to keep it there for button clicks not for random clicks on form.

Comment: I would like to help you more, but my Python is very basic. I still think that you're creating OnClick event for whole form, not the button. I don't know what ANSYS uses for python GUI either, it's been some 15+ years since I used ANSYS extensively, there was no python support back then. Try to search SO with "OnClick" and the environment (like Flask, PyQt, etc.) for specific examples and solutions. Also, are you using ANSYS Developer Guide? It's available in PDF on the internet.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 I figured it out. Check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using conflicting name in the click event

```
def OnClick()
```

which i changed to some other name and it worked fine.
If anyone runs out in similar problems, check the user defined method names which may be same as inbuilt ones.